# exe and dll referencing dll with the same name and same namespace

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, dll

I have a following problem:
I have two projects in one solution, e.g. `Core.prj` and `Extension.prj`.
Now, `Core.prj` references a dll with name `profile.dll`(v1) and `Extension.prj` references the dll with the same name and same namespace but a different version `profile.dll`(v2). 
`Extension.prj` also references `Core.prj` project.
`Core.prj` has a source file, e.g. `A.cs` with some virtual methods defined in it. `Extension.prj` has a source file, e.g. `B.cs` which has some methods overriding virtual methods defined in `A.cs` from `Core.prj`.

My idea was to build and run `Extension.prj` and to call virtual methods in `A.cs` from overrided methods in `B.cs`. Now, methods in `B.cs` would use types from `profile.dll`(v2) and methods in `A.cs` would use types from `profile.dll`(v1), but this isn't possible since virtual methods from `A.cs` use types from `profile.dll`(v2) and not from `profile.dll`(v1).

Is this idea of referencing different versions of dll, with the same name and namespace, from exe and dll feasible in anyway?

Comment: I know you probably have your reasons but using the different versions of the same library at runtime is a nightmare you want to avoid at all costs. You can certainly have different versions of the same library available on the environment and just use assembly redirects to "upgrade" which version an application uses, but this is generally applied across-solution, not intra-solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the `extern alias` directive in this case.

From MSDN:

> To reference two assemblies with the same fully-qualified type names,
>   an alias must be specified at a command prompt, as follows:
>
> /r:GridV1=grid.dll
>
> /r:GridV2=grid20.dll
>
> This creates the external aliases GridV1 and GridV2. To use these
>   aliases from within a program, reference them by using the extern
>   keyword. For example:
>
> extern alias GridV1;
>
> extern alias GridV2;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx